# update 8.2.7 to 8.3.0 with composer

Tags: 8, updating, composer

I want to update with composer (running [the drupal composer drupal project](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project)), and already succesfully updated 8.2.6 - 8.2.7, but now it doesnt update to 8.3.0

```
$ composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies
Package "drupal/core" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

Answer (score 1):

Taken from: [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2751029)

You need to make sure that **drupal/core** is in the require part of your **composer.json** and not the **replace** part, it won't work otherwise.

Haven't tested it yet, but it explains the **Package "drupal/core" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.** message.

In case someone's looking for the way to upgrade using drush:

```
drush up drupal
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a dull moment and was running in the web directory, not in the parent directory with the composer.json.